# finding primes in a list, then printing them

Tags: python-3.x

i have to generate primes for a project at school. heres the requirement: The Sieve of Eratosthenes is an elegant algorithm for finding all of the prime numbers up to some limit n.  The basic idea is to first create a list of numbers from 2 to n.  The first number is removed from the list, and announced as a prime number, and all multiples of the number up to n are removed from the list.  This process continues until the list is empty.  For example, if we wished to find all the primes up to 10, the list would originally contain [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].  The 2 is removed and announced to be prime.  Then 4, 6, 8, and 10 are removed, since they are multiples of 2.  That leaves [3, 5, 7, 9].  Repeating the process, 3 is announced as prime, and 9 is removed because it is a multiple of 9.  That leaves [5, 7].  And so on.  Write a program called generatePrimes.py that prompts the user for a number n and outputs all the primes less than or equal to n.  im lost

Comment: This is not a code writing service, if you have a specific problem you can ask about that but not just post an assignment.

Comment: @KarlReid Mod is not required for a prime sieve... Just a mere for-loop.

Comment: Oh yeah, now that I've looked at some code, that makes sense- I would have just iterated and checked for mod being 0, horribly inefficient. I guess that's why I always fail my programming interviews.

Answer (score 1):

This question is of *terrible* quality and doesn't really deserve an answer, but here is a function for the sieve being described:

```
def pSieve(limit):
     flags = [True] * limit
     flags[0] = flags[1] = False
     primes = []
     for index, flag in enumerate(flags):
         if flag:
             primes.append(index)
             for n in range(index * index, limit, index):
                 flags[n] = False
     return primes
```

and you can see that it produces the correct results:

```
>>> pSieve(10)
[2, 3, 5, 7]
>>> pSieve(100)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pSieve(n):
    m = (n-1) 
    b = [True]*m
    i,p,ps = 0,3,[2]
    while p*p < n:
        if b[i]:
            ps.append(p)
            j = 2*i*i + 6*i + 3
            while j < m:
                b[j] = False
                j = j + 2*i + 3
        i+=1; p+=2
    while i < m:
        if b[i]:
            ps.append(p)
        i+=1; p+=2
    return ps
```